# How to setState within panResponder's release event?

Tags: react-native, setstate, panresponder

Inside a class component, I have a `panResponder` and during the `onPanResponderRelease` event, I want to update the state of the class component. However, the state never gets updated after the setState is called.

```
type ExampleState = {
    duration: number
};

class Example extends Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {
    constructor(props: ExampleProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            duration: 0
        };

        this.setupPanResponder();
    }

    setupPanResponder = (): void => {
        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => false,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
            onPanResponderGrant: () => {
                // grant code here
            },
            onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
                // move code here
            },
            onPanResponderRelease: () => {
                this.setState({ duration: 0 }); // does not seem to actually be setting the state
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Why is the setState not working? If I use setState inside another event, like `onPanResponderMove`, it does seem to work which is strange to me.

Comment: check whether onPanResponderRelease is actually being called. console log inside onPanResponderRelease

Comment: Yup it is. I have one before and after the setState checking the value of this.state.duration. it is the same even after setState.

Comment: the reason might be that actually the state is not getting changed as new value (aka 0) is equal to old value (aka 0) . Try changing to  this.setState({ duration: 1 });

Comment: Or try another variant         this.setState((state, props) => ({
  duration: 0
}));

Comment: Tried that, same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The way I fixed this issue was as follows:

If one of the PanResponder's events depends on a variable representing the state of your component, then you need to recreate the PanResponder every time the dependency changes (whenever you call this.setState({ dependency: new_value })).

Here's an example using a piece of a Functional Component. In this case, if the onPanResponderRelease callback changes, the panResponder will be recreated.

```
const [panResponder, setPanResponder] = useState<PanResponderInstance | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
 setPanResponder(PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onPanResponderRelease: onPanResponderRelease
 }));
}, [onPanResponderRelease]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `setState` should technically work correctly inside the `onPanResponderRelease` method if it's being called properly. However, there might be some surrounding circumstances or external factors affecting its behavior.

Here are some steps and considerations to troubleshoot and fix the issue:

1. **Logging**:

   - Add some logging to your `onPanResponderRelease` method to ensure that it is being called.

```
onPanResponderRelease: () => {
    console.log('onPanResponderRelease called');
    this.setState({ duration: 1 }, () => {
        console.log('state after update:', this.state);
    });
}
```

2. **Check for Error Messages**:

   - Look in the console for any error messages or warnings that might indicate why `setState` isn't working as expected.
3. **Binding Context**:

   - It seems like you're using arrow functions which should automatically bind `this` to the class instance, but if for some reason the context is lost, you might experience issues with `setState`. Ensure `this` refers to the correct context within `onPanResponderRelease`:

```
console.log(this);  // log this to ensure it refers to the class instance
```

4. **Asynchronous Updates**:

   - Remember that `setState` is asynchronous. If you need to perform actions after state is updated, use the callback parameter of `setState`:

```
this.setState({ duration: 0 }, () => {
    // state has been updated
});
```

5. **Check Other Parts of Code**:

   - Ensure there's nothing else in your code that could be preventing the state update or overriding it. For example, check if there are any conditions elsewhere that reset the `duration` state back to its original value.
6. **Component Updating**:

   - Ensure your component is not being unmounted or blocked from updating by a `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

Inspecting the console logs, checking for errors, and verifying the context and other parts of your code should help pinpoint the issue or provide more insight into what's going wrong.